# PHPSecLib Password protected RSA and user authentication

Tags: php, ssh, rsa, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to connect to a SSH2 server through SFTP in PHP using PHPSecLib. But my problem is that, the server requires a key file that is password protected but also username and password. It seems like that it's only possible to provide either username + password or username + keyfile (optionally password protected).

How can I sign on using all these things?

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

My code looks as

```
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->setPassword('keypwd');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('ssh_file.ppk'));

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('hostname', 22);

if (!$sftp->login('username', $key))
  echo 'Failed';
else
  echo 'Success';
```

But where should I put 'password'?

-- Edit: The server only requires the RSA key, but somehow the key is not loaded properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example specifying how to load a password protected key file [on the phpseclib website](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#encrsakey).  Note the line `$key->setPassword('whatever');`

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->setPassword('whatever');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

Keep in mind you're not sending the password to the server.  You just need the password in order to successfully load the key file.  Then the username and key are sent to the server to authenticate you.

Comment: I've discovered that the problem is due to something else, added the note to the post, sorry about that.

Comment: Are you able to use the key file to login with PuTTY or another SSH/SFTP client?  If not, then I suspect a bad key file.

Comment: Hah.. The key file is DSA, the script requires RSA. What a shame :(

Comment: Can you get an RSA key file that will work, or convert your DSA key to an RSA key?  I'm not familiar with the different key formats, so I don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: I wonder, could you import the key into PuTTY Key Generator, and then export it out as an RSA key? http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/

Comment: I'm accepting your answer Josh, since Thermech says it works. I cannot test this anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Unsolvable since the script requires RSA and the key is DSA